# Is there a way to share a windows 8 app still in development?

Tags: windows-8

I'm in the process of developing a Windows 8 desktop application. Is there a way to share this with other Windows 8 users before it's finished or added to the windows store? With standard C# apps you can go into the bin folder and share the .exe, but there is no .exe file when developing with html/css/js.

The goal is to hand out my unfinished app to several friends who have different displays, different settings, different hardware, etc. and make sure I'm happy with the user experience before going further. I'd also like to get their feedback on the UI and several of them are not close enough to just invite over to show.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh405417.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can package your application in Visual Studio as if you want to upload it to Windows Store. It will generate some files. The most important are the APPX file and the PowerShell script. Copy the entire folder to another computer and run the PowerShell script. It will ask you for Microsoft Developer Credentials.